# custom sort my array of objects based on their status property

Tags: javascript

I have to sort my array of objects based on their status property

for example, I have the following array

```
[
{userName:"One", status:"Live"},
{userName:"Two", status:"Rejected"},
{userName:"Three", status:"To Do"},
{userName:"Four", status:"Verify"},
{userName:"Five", status:"Received"},
{userName:"Six", status:"In Progress"}
]
```

after sorting, I need an array that looks like

```
[
{userName:"Three", status:"To Do"},
{userName:"Five", status:"Received"},
{userName:"Six", status:"In Progress"},
{userName:"Two", status:"Rejected"},
{userName:"Four", status:"Verify"},
{userName:"One", status:"Live"}
]
```

Need to sort the items based on its status property in following order

1. To Do
2. Received
3. In Progress
4. Rejected
5. Verify
6. Live

There can be more than one item with same status.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: Can't help you with your homework unless you show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 18):

You can define an array of status in order, and then use the status' index to sort the array.

```js
let status = {
  'To Do': 1,
  'Received': 2,
  'In Progress': 3,
  'Rejected': 4,
  'Verify': 5,
  'Live': 6
};

let data = [{
    userName: "One",
    status: "Live"
  },
  {
    userName: "Two",
    status: "Rejected"
  },
  {
    userName: "Three",
    status: "To Do"
  },
  {
    userName: "Four",
    status: "Verify"
  },
  {
    userName: "Five",
    status: "Received"
  },
  {
    userName: "Six",
    status: "In Progress"
  }
];

data.sort((a, b) => status[a.status] - status[b.status]);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `var status = [ ... ].reduce((o, k, i) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: i}), {})` and `data.sort((a, b) => status[a.status] - status[b.status])` changes O(N) `indexOf()` to O(1) property access.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts -- was working on it. But I don't know why it doesn't work in SO's snippet, but works perfectly fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4ut3cnz/).

Comment: There's a global variable `status` in the snippet, change `var` to `let` and it works. This is why ES6 is a thing. Also `data = data.sort(...)` is redundant. the `sort()` method operates in-place, so there's no need for the assignment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts -- that was the catch! Thanks for pointing it out.